# What is this formula called?

Tags: statistics, average, queueing-theory

I have the average number of incoming ($\lambda $) and outgoing ($\mu$) events, which pass through a system. I know that I can calculate the average number of events in the system using this expression:

$$\frac \lambda {\mu-\lambda} $$

What is that formula called? What words would someone else have to Google for, to find a description of it?

Comment: In queueing theory,( queueing models, waiting line models), it is called the average number of customers in the system.